# Ejected expo app with java reserved word as package name

Tags: java, android, react-native, expo

I have an issue and I know someone already solved this.

I had my app in the expo managed workflow for a while and now we are getting more users and I need a more powerfull local DB. So i ejected my app. Problem is, for noobiness of mine my android packageName is "com.[...].new"

I have made all the adjustments necessary to build my project, but now android studio is telling it cant use this package name as "new" is a reserved word in Java. Curiously expo managed to build with this package name, so i know it is possible.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that Expo did something on their end that allowed this. You can't use a reserved keyword in a package name.

`com.int.something` should also fail compilation.

The Java documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) recommends adding an underscore to the package name if it's a reserved keyword.